# Не вешается команда на крон

Tags: битрикс, cron

Поставил плагин. Не работает.
Вот этот плагин: https://marketplace.1c-bitrix.ru/solutions/sibcode.autopost/
ТП пишет что нужно на крон повесить агенты. Шлет скрины 1 и 2, типа надо поправить.
https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/bitrix/components/bitrix/forum.interface/show_file.php?fid=30375320
https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/bitrix/components/bitrix/forum.interface/show_file.php?fid=30375320&width=500&height=500

Пытаюсь поправить, в заданиях крона (В ISP Manager) пишу команду на выполнение скрипта из файла, как указано на скринах. Получаю ошибку (скрин 3)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Без проблем) Не картикной)
root# /var/www/***/data/www/*********/bitrix/modules/main/tools/cron_events.php
/var/www/***/data/www/*********/bitrix/modules/main/tools/cron_events.php: 1: /var/www/***/data/www/*********/bitrix/modules/main/tools/cron_events.php: cannot open ?php: No such file
/var/www/dzentour/data/www/test.dzen-tour.ru/bitrix/modules/main/tools/cron_events.php: 2: /var/www/dzentour/data/www/test.dzen-tour.ru/bitrix/modules/main/tools/cron_events.php: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Answer (score 0):

По-видимому, отсутствует собственно команда вызова интерпретатора php.
Нужно не

```
/var/www/***/data/www/*********/bitrix/modules/main/tools/cron_events.php
```

а

```
php /var/www/***/data/www/*********/bitrix/modules/main/tools/cron_events.php
```

Comment: root# php /var/www/***/data/www/***/bitrix/modules/main/tools/cron_events.php
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'static' (T_STATIC) in /var/www/***/data/www***/bitrix/modules/main/lib/error.php on line 44

Это вот ошибка при таком раскладе появляется

Comment: Проверьте, что у вас в командной строке и в кроне вызывается та же версия PHP, что и на сайте. Бывает, что сайт работает на PHP 8, а в командной строке вызывается PHP 7.